# Basic create-react-app setup throwing error for react-stripe-elements

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I've tried this locally as well and gotten the same error, but as you can see in from this basic code snippet in [code sand box instance](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym9128k73z) I'm getting this error:

```
Please load Stripe.js (https://js.stripe.com/v3/) on this page to use react-stripe-elements. If Stripe.js isn't available yet (it's loading asynchronously, or you're using server-side rendering), see https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#advanced-integrations
```

This is happening even though I'm simply including the StripeProvider with a key at root. I see that this is clearly not a problem in the [jsfiddle example from the docs](https://jsfiddle.net/attystripe/xux7qzch/), which doesn't use create-react-app. Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add a script tag to your `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"/>
```

Comment: This is correct, it seems weird that you need to load a script tag as well as include an instance of stripe in my bundle. Thanks Colin